# Clearing a directory with specific parameters

Tags: date, powershell, subdirectory

I'm trying to create a scheduled task to clear a development directory of old code. I've seen some examples that come close, but there a couple of things I can't seem to get quite right.

First there are no files in the root directory I'm working with. It's full of sub directories. Of the sub directories, I need to keep two, with all of their contents no matter what. The rest of the directories get deleted, along with their contents if they are over 14 days old. Nothing in any of the directories needs to be sorted by date. Just the initial top level directory's dates should be considered. Here is what I have that isn't working right...  It's deleting everything in the folder, much to my dismay!

```powershell
# Set folder path
$dump_path = "C:\TEMP"
# Set min age of files
$max_days = "-14"
# Get the current date
$curr_date = Get-Date
# Determine how far back we go based on current date
$del_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)
# Delete the files older than x days on the main folder level (Folders Excluded)
Get-ChildItem $dump_path | ?{ !$_.PsIsContainer } | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date } | Remove-Item -Force -Confirm:$False
# Delete the folders (and all included content) older than x days on the main folder level (Files Excluded)
Get-ChildItem $dump_path |? {$_.psiscontainer -and $_.lastwritetime -le (get-date).adddays(-14) -and (-not($_.name -eq "SoftwareInventory;atms"))} | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$False
```

I appreciate any help I can get, getting this to work. I did not write this code. It is piecemeal from this and other sites, putting pieces I found together, trying to get it to work. I'm pretty new at coding.

Comment: Is  "SoftwareInventory" "atms" the 2 folders you need to keep?\

Comment: Yes, those two directories and everything under them should be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If feel like your issue is coming from this clause in your `Where-Object`

```
-not($_.name -eq "SoftwareInventory;atms")
```

Are "SoftwareInventory" and "atms" the folders you are trying to keep? If so that syntax will not work since It is looking for match to a folder literally called "SoftwareInventory;atms". I think we need a little update on that clause

```
("SoftwareInventory","atms" -notcontains $_.name)
```

So that uses `-notcontains` and will match all folders that are not named "SoftwareInventory" or "atms"

**Bad Quotes?**

Usually this is a copy paste error but you had odd quotes in your question that I removed.

- “ Can cause issues
- " standard quote

Comment: Matt, will this keep everything under those excluded directories as well? I'll test this first thing Monday!

Comment: It wont delete anything under those directories since you are not using `-recurse` with `Get-ChildItem`. This should work as you intended. Always test first.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this worked perfectly. I even removed the files section! Thanks for the assist!